# Create user profile using CSOM in a On-Prem SP 2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

I need to create user profiles in the User Profile service, and I need to use the Client Side Object Model. The SP server is a on-Prem SharePoint 2013 server.
How can this be implemented?

Comment: Aside from "create a user profile". What are you trying to accomplish?Because usually you don't need to create profiles manually, the system does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

User Profiles cannot be created or Updated using CSOM as of now. You can update user profile properties using CSOM in SPO but not in On-Prem.

[image]

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/work-with-user-profiles-in-sharepoint

You can create user profile in SP 2013 server with Server Side Object Model.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-work-with-user-profiles-and-organization-profiles-by-using-the-server-obj